# Override System Fonts

Tags: android, fonts, overriding

I want my app to have its own fonts. i don't want it to use the systems fonts. Is there any way to use the fonts provided by the app instead of the Default System Fonts ?

Basically i have included (already tried) : `android:fontFamily="sans-serif"` in the text view

Complete Layout Parameters for the textview :

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TVcontrolStructures"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="#ecf0f1"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="TVClick"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Control Structures"
                    android:textColor="#2c3e50"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
```

But still when i run it on my phone, it gives the system fonts instead of these fonts.

also i did not find any question relative.

What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library.
First add gradle dependency:

`compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'`

Then Create a folder called `fonts` in `Assets` folder and paste your fonts in it.
For setting a textView font:
`<TextView fontPath="fonts/MyFont.ttf"/>`

Installation
Define your default font using CalligraphyConfig, in your **Application class** in the `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-RobotoRegular.ttf")
                            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build()
            );
    //....
}
```

Comment: So i can apply the fonts to the text view even without using the Installation ?
Like what should i do if i want two different fonts for two different text views. Obviously i cannot make both of them default

Comment: The installation is a initialization for Library in order to apply it's features to app, So it must be added. I personally use this to customize fonts in my apps.

Comment: but even after using this library, on some devices the system fonts still show up instead of the custom fonts.. and while on the other devices it works perfectly

Comment: I guess for some reason they fail to load the font. It depends on various reasons, like API level, resolution, etc. Try using other fonts on that device. See is it the lib or the device or the font.